# Redux-Logger not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-logger

I can not connect the logger, I tried everything

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';
import {hydrate} from 'drator';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';

const logger = createLogger();
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, promiseMiddleware, logger)(createStore);
const state = hydrate('App');

export default createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, state);
```

Version "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",

I've used this isomorphic Redux repository https://github.com/ryardley/reduxor

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Are you getting an error or does it just not do anything?

Comment: @ScottBamforth just on console show nothing

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong without testing it as your post could do with a bit more detail but it looks like you're calling the `createStore` and `applyMiddleware` functions the wrong way around.

Normally I do it like this

```
import logger from 'redux-logger'
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
)
```

This way `applyMiddleware` is an argument in `createStore`

See here for reference https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger#usage

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Use compose to apply middlewares.

```
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';


import rootReducer from '../reducers';

let store = null;

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  // Check to avoid multiple configured stores
  if (store) {
    return store;
  }
  const middlewares = [thunk, promiseMiddleware, logger];
  store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
  );
  return store;
}
```